# PHP- select specific row from MySQL database

Tags: php, database, mysqli, row

I Need to select a specific row from a MySQLi database based off of a value in it.

For example I have a Table with a column named "house", and under that column there are maybe 5 rows with the title "house1" and three rows with the title "house2". I only want to select the rows that have "house1" in them.

This is my code

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Hockey WHERE house = house1 ORDER BY attendance desc";
```

I then want it to make a table with only values from a row if the house is Jacksons

right now if I delete the WHERE part from my query it will make a table but it will have rows from both houses (Jacksons and Martlands)

Thanks!

Comment: Syntax is correct, just enclose **house1** within single-quote commas. I don't see what the question is here, you have answered it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Hockey WHERE house = 'house1' ORDER BY attendance desc";
```